# Angular material sidenav under the header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use an angular material sidenav. Everything works as expected but th e sidenav is sliding over the header. How can I fix that? I created a planker to be able to see my code, but the planker doesn't work as expected. Thank you in advance for the help. https://plnkr.co/edit/gr5n1AbBHADWY4L72MMg?p=preview

This is a part of my code the rest could be seen in Plunker

```
 <div>
     <md-toolbar class="md-accent">
          <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
              <h2>Logo here</h2>
          </div>
     </md-toolbar>
     </div>
     <div ng-controller="AdminController as ctrl" class="md-content" ng-cloak>
        <section layout="row" flex>
           <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left"
                            md-disable-backdrop md-whiteframe="4">
           <md-content layout-margin>
               <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-accent">
                   Close this Sidenav
               </md-button>
           </md-content>
                </md-sidenav>
                <md-content flex layout-padding>
                    <div layout="column">
                        <div>
                            <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-raised">
                                Toggle Sidenav
                            </md-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </md-content>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the md-button outside

```
 <section layout="row" flex>
    <md-content flex layout-padding>
      <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
        <h2>Logo here</h2>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-button ng-click="clickSide('left')"> Toggle Sidenav</md-button>
    </md-content>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left">
      <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav left</h1>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content layout-padding="">
        <md-tabs>
        </md-tabs>
      </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>
  </section>
```

**EDIT:**
Embed the  SideNav and Content in a `<md-content flex></md-content>`

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rwtkrr5dgrG1XtiD1Vsl?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you. The sidenav still overlaps the header.

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan now the demo works. How can I make the main section to slide to the right when the side div is sliding to the right. And take the size of the whole page whenever the side div is hidden.

Comment: @user6934713 you need to read on layout https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment . mark as answer if it has helped